# Copy only Specific text of a file to another

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

I have a file abc.txt the contents are

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="Sources"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERExtensions"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERJars"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERPrototypes"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaEOAccess"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaEOControl"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaFoundation"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaJDBCAdaptor"/>
```

I want to copy all the paths into another file. That is I want my output text file to look like:

```
    WOFramework/ERExtensions
    WOFramework/ERJars
    WOFramework/ERPrototypes
    WOFramework/JavaEOAccess
    WOFramework/JavaEOControl
    WOFramework/JavaFoundation
    WOFramework/JavaJDBCAdaptor
```

Comment: you want to copy depending on kind?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to extract parts of an XML document.  Try an XML tool such as `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing

Comment: `cut -d '"' -f4`?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, your answer should be the best solution :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume the file follows the same pattern. If that is the case, you can have a command like below.

```
grep -o ' path=.*$' file.txt | cut -c8- |rev | cut -c 4- | rev
```

So, I open the file using `cat` and then I extract only the characters from `path=` and then I remove the unwanted characters using `cut` and then I use the `rev` technique to remove unwanted characters from the end.

**Another awk approach**

```
awk -F'path="' '{print $2}' file.txt |rev | cut -c 4- | rev
```

I use the `path="` as delimiter and print all the information after it. And the `rev` basically does the same as above.

**Testing**

```
cat file.txt
<classpathentry kind="src" path="Sources"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERExtensions"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERJars"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERPrototypes"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaEOAccess"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaEOControl"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaFoundation"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaJDBCAdaptor"/>
```

After running the command,

```
Sources
WOFramework/ERExtensions
WOFramework/ERJars
WOFramework/ERPrototypes
WOFramework/JavaEOAccess
WOFramework/JavaEOControl
WOFramework/JavaFoundation
WOFramework/JavaJDBCAdaptor
```

A better approach as provided by Stephane in comments.

```
cut -d '"' -f4 file.txt
```

Comment: He doesn't want "Sources"

Comment: Actually, I guess he accepted it - so what do I know?

Answer (score 7):

A simple approach with `awk`:

```
awk -F\" '/WOF/ {print $4}' abc.txt > outfile
```

- `-F\"` changes the field separator from the default (a space) to a quote mark (escaped with `\`)
- `/WOF/` restricts the returned results of each record (line of the file) to those that match the pattern: `WOF`
- `$4` is the fourth field for each of those matching records, the path.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach with grep and cut:

```
grep "kind=\"con\"" sample.txt | cut -d \" -f 4 > sample_edited.txt
```

This will grep all lines containing `kind="con"` and print the paths by setting `cut`'s delimiter to `"`.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -n '/.*="con"[^"]*./{s///;s/..>//p}' <<\DATA

<classpathentry kind="src" path="Sources"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERExtensions"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERJars"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERPrototypes"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaEOAccess"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaEOControl"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaFoundation"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaJDBCAdaptor"/>
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
WOFramework/ERExtensions
WOFramework/ERJars
WOFramework/ERPrototypes
WOFramework/JavaEOAccess
WOFramework/JavaEOControl
WOFramework/JavaFoundation
WOFramework/JavaJDBCAdaptor
```

This should get only the *WO*... stuff, I think. It's also fully portable.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution if your version of `grep` supports PCRE-style lookarounds

```
grep -oP '(?<=kind="con" path=").+?(?="/>)' abc.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`

```
sed -e 's/.*path="//' -e 's:"/>$::' abc.txt > output_file
```

Comment: sed -e 's/.*path="//' -e 's:".*$::' abc.txt > output_file  -- dropping everything after the last quote instead of specific matching at the end.

Comment: it display extra lines.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, where are you seeing extra lines in the OP's input data? The answer above is tailored to the OP's data.

Comment: it displays `sources` also according to the op's input.

Answer (score 2):

If the file format is really fixed, then the approach below is **not** as efficient as many of the other answers you already got.

So this is in the case that the file format changes or can not be relied upon (or turns out it can't be relied upon after doing a "brute force" extraction and coming up with "paths" such as `kind=`). Unfortunately, my experience is that "constant and guaranteed" formats simply aren't. Or not for long.

First you convert all the tags into newlines, so that you don't have to worry about multiple tags in one line or text disposition.

```
tr "<>" "\n\n" < source.txt
```

then you select the rows containing the single word "path" followed by space(s) and an equal sign

```
| grep "\<path\\s*="
```

from these lines, you extract the "path" component; this way you do not have to worry about what happens if some tags have attributes in a slightly different format

```
| sed -e 's/.*path\s*=\s*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
# You can modify the above to handle single quotes as well as double quotes
# using [\'"] instead of "
```

and finally, possibly, you may want to get each path only once

```
| sort | uniq
```

Wrapping it in a single line,

```
tr "<>" "\n\n" < source.txt | grep "\<path\\s*=" | sed -e 's/.*path\s*=\s*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' | sort | uniq > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has posted one yet, here are a few Perl solutions:

```
perl -ne  's/.*con.*="(.+)".*/$1/ && print' file
```

#### Explanation

The `-ne` means "Read the input file line by line and apply the script passed by `-e`". The `s/foo/bar/` is the substitution operator, it will replace `foo` with `bar`. In this case, the replacement will be whatever was matched in the parentheses, this is `$1`. The regex means "match everything up to `con`, then the longest string until a `=` and then capture everything between the quotes. The `&& print` will print the modified line only if the replacement was successful.

```
perl -e  'print grep{s/.*con.*=.(.+)".*/$1/}<>' file
```

#### Explanation

This one is a bit more idiomatic. It will print the result of applying the same substitution as used above to each line of the input file (`<>`). Just a different way of writing the same basic approach.

```
perl -F'[="]' -lane 'print $F[5] if $F[2]=~/con/' file
```

#### Explanation

The `-a` makes `perl` behave like `awk`, it automatically splits the input line into fields (saved as the `@F` array) on the character(s) passed by the `-F` parameter. Since I tell it to split on `=` or `"`, the 5th field will be what we're after and it is only printed if the 2nd field matches `con`. The `-l` adds a newline to each `print` call (and other things that are not relevant).

---

And here's another `grep` one. This will print all matches of `letters/letters`, it works correctly on your example but might not on a more complex one:

```
grep -Eio '[a-z]+/[a-z]+' file
```

---

And a pure shell one (bash/zsh/ksh):

```
while IFS='=' read a b c; do 
    [[ "$b" =~ "con" ]] && a=${c/%?\/>/} && echo ${a/#?}; 
done <  file
```

#### Explanation

The `while read; do ... ; done < file` loops through each line of the file. Setting `IFS` to `=` splits each line at `=` and `read a b c` saves each field in the variables `$a` through `$c`. Then, if `$b` matches `con`, the last three characters are removed from `$c` and the result is saved as `$a` and then printed with the first character (the quote) removed. See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for more on  bash's string manipulation options.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
while IFS=\" read -r _ _ _ f4 _; do
    case $f4 in
        */*) echo "$f4";;
    esac
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

And the one through GNU sed's backreferencing,

```
sed -nr 's/^.*kind=\"con\" path=\"([^"]*)\".*$/\1/p' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat aa
<classpathentry kind="src" path="Sources"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERExtensions"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERJars"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/ERPrototypes"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaEOAccess"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaEOControl"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaFoundation"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="WOFramework/JavaJDBCAdaptor"/>
data

$ sed -nr 's/^.*kind=\"con\" path=\"([^"]*)\".*$/\1/p' aa
WOFramework/ERExtensions
WOFramework/ERJars
WOFramework/ERPrototypes
WOFramework/JavaEOAccess
WOFramework/JavaEOControl
WOFramework/JavaFoundation
WOFramework/JavaJDBCAdaptor
```